# pdoc3 ValueError: File or module 'xxx' not found if imported from other package

Tags: python, documentation-generation, pdoc

pdoc3 is a nice tool to generate documentation from code. In one of my projects, I got some exception. Wonder if it is caused by project structure. These are the folder structure of my two projects.

```
proj_A
  -src
    -automation
      -hl7ctl
        (has a definition of HL7CtlClient)

proj_B
  -src
    -automation
      -connctl
        -core.py
        -utility.py (uses HL7CtlClient)
```

In the utility.py of the proj_B, I have to import a class from project_A

```
from automation.hl7ctl import HL7CtlClient
```

This causes the following error by running pdoc3 at src folder in proj_B. The proj_A has been installed by using 'sudo pip3 install proje_A.gz'

automation.connctl.core No module named 'automation.hl7ctl' in pdoc3's code:

(See [https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc/blob/master/pdoc/**init**.py#L519](https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc/blob/master/pdoc/__init__.py#L519))

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pdoc3", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pdoc3==0.5.5.dev13+g43f28dd.d20190427', 'console_scripts', 'pdoc3')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pdoc3-0.5.5.dev13+g43f28dd.d20190427-py3.6.egg/pdoc/cli.py", line 419, in main
    for module in args.modules]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pdoc3-0.5.5.dev13+g43f28dd.d20190427-py3.6.egg/pdoc/cli.py", line 419, in <listcomp>
    for module in args.modules]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pdoc3-0.5.5.dev13+g43f28dd.d20190427-py3.6.egg/pdoc/__init__.py", line 943, in __init__
    m, docfilter=docfilter, supermodule=self, context=self._context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pdoc3-0.5.5.dev13+g43f28dd.d20190427-py3.6.egg/pdoc/__init__.py", line 943, in __init__
    m, docfilter=docfilter, supermodule=self, context=self._context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pdoc3-0.5.5.dev13+g43f28dd.d20190427-py3.6.egg/pdoc/__init__.py", line 940, in __init__
    m = import_module(fullname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pdoc3-0.5.5.dev13+g43f28dd.d20190427-py3.6.egg/pdoc/__init__.py", line 520, in import_module
    raise ValueError('File or module {!r} not found'.format(module))
ValueError: File or module 'automation.connctl.core' not found
```

This is how I run pdoc3:

```
cd src
pdoc3 --overwrite --html --html-dir ../docs/APIs --template-dir ../docs/templates automation
```

There are `__init__.py` in automation and its subfolders but not 'src'.

The automation/`__init__.py` has the following content:

```
__import__("pkg_resources").declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Comment: How do you run pdoc, `pdoc3 --html project_B/src`? Is _project\_*/src/automation_ a [namespace package](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) without _\_\_init\_\_.py_?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have updated the question. So once I run it as you just suggested, it failed at parsing the `__init__.py` in the automation folder. After I removed all the content of the `__init.py__`, it builds successfully. I wonder why. The '__import__("pkg_resources").declare_namespace(__name__)' is an inheirted code.

Comment: Would you be willing to construct a [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) zip archive and post it on [GitHub](https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc) as a new issue? The module importation system, particularly as far as namespace packages go, needs a slight revamp.

Comment: Thanks K3. I restructure my package so to use the implicit namespace of the PEP-420 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/. Now there is no problem. Mixing implicit namespace and some older way might be the reason why it didn't work. The pdoc3 does what it supposes to do.  Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to test namespace package importing improvements in https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc/pull/62. This should land in v0.6.0 shortly.

Answer (score 2):

pydoc and pdoc read your code!!!

if you will run it from the same directory `pdoc --html .` or `pydoc -w .`
it should work if all the modules are in the same directory. but if they are not:

make sure your modules in each directory has it sys full path appendded.

```
sys.path.append("D:/Coding/project/...the path the model is in")
```

Or, even better, you can make python to get the path:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(path)
```

Relative path will not do the trick!

Comment: `pdoc --html .` was the answer for me, :+1: